# PHP's str_replace not working?

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to do a simple task of storing an Email template into a Database, retrieving it and populating variables in the template before sending an email.

I am using `str_replace` but for some reason it is not working for me.  To complicate it more, it works for 1 of my template variables below, the `{{date}}` one does get populated but all the others get skipped.

It is not an issue with my POST variables not being populated, I can even pass in a real text string in `str_replace` and it will still not find my "template variables" and replace them.  Just the date one.

Any ideas why it would have such odd behavior?  From what I can see, the Date one has nothing different?

**Template**

```
$admin_template = '<table>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>{{name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Email:</strong></td><td>{{email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Website:</strong></td><td>{{website}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td>{{phone}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Source:</strong></td><td>{{source}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Budget:</strong></td><td>{{budget}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>IP:</strong></td><td>{{{ip}}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Date Submitted:</strong></td><td>{{date}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Message:</strong></td><td>{{message}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>';
```

**Code to Process Template**

```
// Process Admin Template
$admin_body = str_replace('{{name}}', $name, $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{email}}', $mailFrom, $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{phone}}', $_POST["phone"], $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{website}}', $_POST["website"], $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{message}}', $_POST["message"], $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{budget}}', $_POST["budget"], $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{source}}', $_POST["source"], $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{ip}}', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $admin_template);
$admin_body = str_replace('{{date}}', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $admin_template);
```

**Actual Output After Processing**

```
// Actual Output...
<table>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Name:</strong></td><td>{{name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Email:</strong></td><td>{{email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Website:</strong></td><td>{{website}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td><td>{{phone}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Source:</strong></td><td>{{source}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Budget:</strong></td><td>{{budget}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>IP:</strong></td><td>{{{ip}}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Date Submitted:</strong></td><td>2013-05-26 05:01:14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>Message:</strong></td><td>{{message}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: check the server and post vars are what you think they should be. `printr($_POST);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're constantly recreating `$admin_body` from scratch, discarding the previous `str_replace()` substitutions :-D

Comment: side note ... this can call be done in one pass by using arrays for the first and second parameters for str_replace. I always just create an array like `$arr['{{name}}'] = $name; $arr['{{email}}'] = $email...` and call `str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $admin_template);`